# Nativescript Textview multiline select scroll not working properly

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

When creating a long string of text using a TextView on iOS and exceeding the height of the TextView  it will allow you to scroll.
After scrolling back up to the top of the textview and selecting a piece of text my caret position is not correctly set and my textview will not scroll to the "tapped" position. This is probably caused by the overlapping keyboard.

I set up an easy to test template which is:

```html
    <template>
      <Page backgroundColor="#6B00D4" backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar="true" actionBarHidden="true" class="page">
        <GridLayout rows="auto">
          <TextView row="0" height="auto"/>
        </GridLayout>
      </Page>
    </template>
```

How will I be able to get the correct position when tapping on a piece of text?

**EDIT**: Just found out it only seems to happen on iOS 14

**EDIT 2**: The scroll position isn't used when positioning the caret, that's why the caret position seems off from the user tap position

**EDIT 3**: Seems to be a native iOS 14 issue: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662056

Comment: a playground sample would be better to understand and work with your problem.

Comment: @VikasAcharya is that really necessary since the problem exists within the test template, no other code is needed to reproduce my issue.